# Unexpected behaviour with a struct with enum bit field initialization C++14

Tags: c++, struct, enums, visual-studio-2015, bit-fields

I have a struct which a bit field which is of type enum:

```
enum TCDATA_FORMAT { a, b, c, d  }; 
struct ctypetc { TCDATA_FORMAT Input : 16; TCDATA_FORMAT Output : 16; };
```

and up until C++11(VS2013) this initialization worked fine:

```
ctypetc ctyp = { b, c };
```

But with C++14(VS2015 update 1) it initializes Input and Output to 0. Does anyone know why? I am guessing it has something to do with the enum bit fields.

edit :
If I try :

```
ctyp.Input = b;
ctyp.Output = c;
```

It works fine.

Comment: MSVC doesn't have a C++11 mode. What are you talking about?

Comment: more like VS2013 vs VS2015. Edited the question.

Comment: Fast comment, not a real answer: Have you tried to rewrite your enum as an enum class? `enum class TCDATA_FORMAT : short { a, b, c, d } ;`. This way, you can get rid of the bit fields altogether. (you have only 4 items, so I would go as far as using `char` as underlying type, if size was such an issue)

Comment: What version of VS2015? Update 1? 2? 3?

Comment: Definitely compiler bug. [This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/31/visual-c-2015-update-2-bug-fixes/) reports that a bug entitled "C++ Compiler: Enum bit field initialized with wrong value" has been fixed in Update 2, but the link is dead so it's hard to tell if that's the culprit. This code works correctly on my VS 2015 Update 3.

Comment: Those are some creatively shuffled capitalisation practices you have there ;) Anyway, yeah, bug. This works just fine on my `g++-6`, printing the `1` and `2` you expect. And hey, it's very polite of MS to list bugs in such a neat table with names of those who reported them :)

Comment: Cannot reproduce this at http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ (it runs MSC14).